# how to use ws(websocket) via ngrok

Tags: python, websocket, localhost, ngrok, serve

I want to share my local `WebSocket` on the internet but `ngrok` only support `HTTP` but my `ws.py` address is `ws://localhost:8000/`

it is good working on localhost buy is not know how to use this on the internet?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ngrok http 8000` to access it. It will work. Although, ws is altogether a different protocol than http but ngrok handles it internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose websocket server using NGROK

```
ngrok tcp 8000
```

Comment: Note, in this case you have to switch to http or provide custom SSL certificate